# Sort table using async await in protractor

Tags: async-await, protractor

I am trying to sort a data table using async await. Here is my code.

```
let lastActivity = await Promise.all(_.map(elementfinder, function(elm) {
   return elm.getText();
}));

let sortedLastActivity = _.sort(lastActivity);
expect(lastActivity).toEqual(sortedLastActivity);
```

However ***i get an error:-***

> elm.getText() is not a function.

I am unable to understand the bug here. 
Please help!

TIA

Comment: please give the code line to define and init the variable `elementfinder`, we need to know what value you assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `elementfinder` represent only one element, you should change your code to 
 `_map([elementfinder], function(ele){...})`.

And the `elementfinder` must be `ElementArrayFinder` type.